# Mail not sent to my docker container port 1025

Tags: php, docker, codeigniter, docker-compose

I want to use [maildev](https://hub.docker.com/r/maildev/maildev) service for local development. I use docker with 3 main services

- apache-php
- mariadb
- maildev

The two ones work's well but maildev doesn't. I use CodeIgniter 3 for development

I'm able to see UI on port localhost:1080 but port 1025 doesn't work to send mail.

I tried to follow this [example](https://r.je/sendmail-php-docker) with my configuration

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  apache-php:
  container_name: app
  build: 
    context: .
    dockerfile: builds/manager/Dockerfile
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  volumes:
    - ./app/:/var/www/html/public/app
    - ./apache/log/:/var/log/apache2/
    - ./apache/conf/apache.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
    - ./apache/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
  depends_on:
    - mariadb
    - maildev
  networks:
    - backend

maildev:
  image: maildev/maildev
  container_name: maildev
  command: bin/maildev --hide-extensions STARTTLS
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 1080:1080
    - 1025:1025
  networks:
    - backend
```

**Dockerfile apache-php**

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

ENV TZ=Europe/Paris

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    && apt install -y \
        apt-utils \
        git \
        mailutils \
        sendmail \
    \
    && echo "sendmail_path=/usr/sbin/sendmail -S maildev:1025 -t -i" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/sendmail.ini \
    && sed -i '/#!\/bin\/sh/aservice sendmail restart' /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint \
    && sed -i '/#!\/bin\/sh/aecho "$(hostname -i)\t$(hostname) $(hostname).localhost" >> /etc/hosts' /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    \
    &&  a2enmod rewrite \
    \
    &&  service apache2 restart 
    
WORKDIR /var/www/html/
```

**php.ini**

```
SMTP=maildev
smtp_port=1025
sendmail_path=/usr/sbin/sendmail -S maildev:1025 -t -i
```

**email.php**

```
$config['protocol']         = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host']        = 'maildev';
$config['smtp_port']        = 1025;

$config['charset']          = 'utf-8';
$config['mailtype']         = 'html';
$config['crlf']             = '\r\n';
$config['newline']          = '\r\n';
$config['wordwrap']         = TRUE;
$config['send_multipart']   = FALSE;
```

**Running send mail**

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
$from = "test@hostinger-tutorials.fr";
$to = "test@hostinger.fr";
$subject = "Essai de PHP Mail";
$message = "PHP Mail fonctionne parfaitement";
$headers = "De :" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
echo "Email sent";
```

I've no errors but got no email too. Can someone help me to debug this ?